# SparseMatrix kroneckerProduct crashing

Tags: eigen

I'm compiling the following against eigen 3.3.5:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/KroneckerProduct>

template <typename eT, int SIDE>
inline
auto
xLeft(const Eigen::Matrix<eT, SIDE, SIDE> & M)
{
  Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> Id(SIDE, SIDE);
  Id.setIdentity();
  return kroneckerProduct(M.transpose(), Id);
}

void fail()
{
  Eigen::Matrix<double,2,2> M = Eigen::Matrix<double,2,2>::Random();
  std::cout << "die:" << xLeft(M) << "\n";
}

int main() { fail(); return 0; }
```

and getting a crash, anyone else see this, is this an Eigen bug or am I doing something wrong that I just can't see?

also:

```
g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)
```

Comment: You are returning an expression which depends on a local variable (which gets destructed at the end of the method), making the expression invalid.

Comment: See this [doc page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html) for other similar examples with solutions. In your case, either replace `auto` by a `SparseMatrix` or return `kroneckerProduct(M.transpose(), Id).eval()` to let Eigen figure-out the concrete type.